# Magento2: Overriding the catalog widget

Tags: magento2, template

I am trying to override the the catalog widget template found in this directory:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```

I copied the grid.phtml file to:

```
mytheme/Magento_Catalog_Widget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```

But this hasn't worked and the widget I have put on my page is still pulling in the default template. Any ideas? I am pretty sure I am using the right directory as all other template files I have overridden have worked fine. Tried flushing the cache and no joy.

I noticed the code the wysiwyg generates for the widget on the page references a template file. I presume this is still overridden?

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_count="4" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`32`;]]"}}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to just rename your theme module directory like **`Magento_CatalogWidget`**.

New file path for your theme:
    `mytheme/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

When core module name with **`-`**  you have to remove that and make the next character Uppercase.

Eg.:
if you want to override core module `module-catalog-inventory` then your path would be **`Magento_CatalogInventory`**.

Comment: Excellent thank you @Rakesh that has worked. I didn't know you had to remove the second '-'

Comment: Example path should be Magento_CatalogInventory.

Comment: You can find the module name `Magento_CatalogInventory` inside the `registration.php` file in the module. This is the definitive way to name the module within your theme.

Answer (score 0):

New Path should be the following:

theme/Magento_CatalogWidget/web/template/product/widget/content/grid.phtml